# woocommerce variations order details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a B 2 B wholesale website using a less common woocommerce plugin to display the products with many variations and quantities.

In the Order Details page and order confirmation emails - the product variations are displaying incorrectly.

It is showing each instance up to the selected variation. 
(See screenshot, first one is '4XL' - 2nd is 'M')

I am assuming I could do a "temporary/dodgey" fix by having a filter on the 'woocommerce_order_items_meta_display' class, but I honestly have no idea where to start with this.

Am I on the right track at least?

Screenshot: https://s24.postimg.org/45fed3pth/Screen_Shot_2016_12_30_at_10_08_01_am.png

Comment: Which page is this ? Checkout, Cart or Order Details, provide more information. If you have used any custom code to display the variations, provide that as well